# How to copy user permissions in Windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, filesystems, user-permissions, robocopy

I have windows server 2012 r2 and two storage drive. lest say A and B. I have created users and given files and folder access in drive A but now it is crashed and now I want to give all the same user permission in Drive B. I have same folders in both drives. How can I achieve it?  Is there any way to copy the access rights and permissions?

Comment: If drive A is inaccessible then there isn't any way to copy the folder permissions to drive B.

Comment: but in case if it is accessible then is it possible? HOW?

Comment: You should have made your backups preserving permissions if they were intended for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

With drive A being accessible as you added.

`Robocopy` is a built in tool that can do that. `/E` will give you all the subdirectories. Look into using it with the `/sec` flag, but `/copyall` is good too. You'll end up at something like this `robocopy [source] [destination] /S /copyall`. `robocopy /?` for more info.

`xcopy` is another built in tool you can use. `xcopy [source] [destination] /S /K /O /X`. `xcopy /?` for more info.

Comment: Note that if you are copying an entire drive [you need to explicitly exclude the special folders](https://serverfault.com/a/920019/94065).

Answer (score 0):

If drive A is accessible you can clone the permissions to drive B with a tool called Security Explorer by Quest (Buy or Free Try).
It has an option to copy or clone the permissions to another object or folder. See the [manual](http://support-public.cfm.quest.com/35894_SecurityExplorer_9.7_UserGuide_en.pdf)

Good Luck !